# how to make ICS like tabs (white background with sky blue line at the bottom) in android 2.2

Tags: android, android-tabhost

How Do I make deafult ICS style tabs in android 2.2. I don't want to use ActionBarSherlock, instead I need to apply custom drawables. Can someone help ?
I tried using 9.png but didn't help much, as it didn't fill the complete tab, instead it shows only some blurred extended background. If you are suggesting some drawables - Please provide the drawable as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download ready made demo from this link: [ICSStyleTab](https://github.com/Abhan/TabViewPager). I tried it for one of the project and it is working fine. If you wanted to add pager functionality, you can easily add using `FragmentPager` from `Support V4` Library.

Update: ICSStyle Tab With Pager [Demo](https://github.com/Abhan/TabViewPager)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

HoloEverywhere is a library to provide ICS/Holo theme to pre-3.0 devices:

https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere

Even if you really want to write your own code, you can gain a great deal of insight simply by looking into its source.